# What percentage of teleporters would a world with teleportation need, before timezones are required?

Tags: economy, teleportation, time-keeping, logistics, governance

> "Arrive at 3pm"
> "Wait, is that 3pm your time, my time or the
> destination time?"
> "Destination time, it's when the Wizard bar opens
> at hub-city"
> "When is that for me?"
> "Look it up in your book of
> totally-not-timezone details, I'm 3 hours behind, you're three hours
> ahead"
> "So I need to leave at 6pm local, and you leave at 12pm your
> time"
> "That's right!"

At some point "book of totally-not-timezone details" becomes necessary, but how many teleporting wizards whizzing about does it take before it's logistically impossible to make use of them (in the economy, not just for organising wizardly pubcrawls) without time zones?

---

Imagine a world much like ours, before the trains or any other relatively fast transport have been developed (pre-1800s), where timezones as a human construction do not yet exist.

There are however maybe some percentage of advanced wizards (out of a larger number of not-so-advanced wizards) who are able to teleport far enough around the globe as to notice that the sun is not in the same place as when you left. Let's say total number of all people predisposed to wizardhood is under 50% of the global population, and are not naturally predisposed to any location or nationality. Let's say they only started existing in the 1700s, and it's not until 1800 you have any advanced wizards. Wizards advance by practice.

The advanced wizards are powerful enough to do a great deal of damage if somebody tries and fails to coerce them, but being an advanced wizard doesn't predispose you to violence, and I can imagine many wanting to work with governments and organisations. There are never enough advanced wizards to guarantee they could overthrow even moderately sized governments, as I don't want that as an answer (this limitation can and should affect the final answer).

#### Teleportation rules:

- Teleportation always takes at least 1 minute of focus, and any interruption or loss of focus of the wizard prevents the spell from taking place, and they must restart.
- Everyday wizards need 30 minutes rest between each use of their teleportation. Advanced wizards only need 5 minutes if one location is a fixed safe location, otherwise they need 30 minutes. While resting a wizard cannot cast spells.
- All wizards can faultlessly teleport up to 1km away, between any two places.
- All wizards can faultlessly teleport between two fixed locations with the correct glyphs/symbols written on the floor, so long as they know those glyphs/symbols.
- Advanced wizards can faultlessly teleport from anywhere to a fixed locations with the correct glyphs/symbols written on the floor, so long as they know those glyphs/symbols.
- Advanced wizards can teleport between any two unprepared locations, but there is a 1% chance you are instead transported to a location up to 5% off course in one random direction after the first 1km. For example, if you wanted to travel 2km, and you went off course, you could end up 0.05*(2km - 1km) = 50m off course. For 1000km journey, you could end up 0.05*(1000km - 1km) = 49.95km off course.
- Advanced wizards can faultless teleport from anywhere to a location, if they are holding an item that has spent 24 hours in that destination location in the last 6 months. Advanced wizards have perfect knowledge of whether they have a reliable object for this form of teleportation or not.
- You never end up in the middle of the air or an object so long as you do not go off course. I.e. you appear on the ground at your destination, avoiding any obstacles. If you deliberately teleport over  body of water, you appear on the surface.
- Your height above the local area is preserved if you go off course, but there is no correction for the destination elevation. That is, if you teleport from the top of a tower, that is 50ft above street level, you end up 50ft above your destination if you go off course, likewise if you teleport from a basement you potentially end up in the ground.
- Teleporting into a solid object (including other people) means those involved instantly die. If you teleport into a liquid, you do not, but you have to make your own way to the surface.
- Attempting to teleport to a destination, and have not gone off-course, not in a solid object but without enough room at the destination fails. i.e. if somebody puts a crate over the space with the glyph/symbols.
- If you go off course and would would appear somewhere without room you appear a distance further away, that you can occupy up to 0.5% off course. I.e. if you go off-course into a crowded room or a tree canopy you do not appear inside a person or object so long as the nearest unoccupied location is less than 0.5% further off course. i.e. if you teleport 2km, and go 50m off-course and would appear inside a person/cliff face/tree etc, you appear up to but not more than 5m away from that collision, towards an unoccupied space.
- Advanced wizards can take up to 8 other people (and anything they are carrying) with them, or a single object not fixed to the ground that occupies less than a 10ft^3 cube shaped volume.
- All wizards must travel with their teleportees/objects.
- Everyday wizards can only take 1 other person (and anything they are carrying) with them, and no unheld objects.
- Creating safe teleportation locations with glyphs/symbols is inexpensive, but you still need to make the location + glyphs/symbols known to anybody who wishes to visit, and they can only be made by advanced wizards.
- Symbol/glyphs used are always unique otherwise they fail to work as a fixed destination.
- The above point can be abused to brute force and find a safe location.
- You cannot derive the location of a safe teleportation location from it's glyphs/symbols.

#### Wizard training rules

- Predisposition to everyday wizardhood is only detectable by wizards, and only after the age of 10 in all genders.
- Predisposition to advanced wizardhood is only detectable by advanced wizards, and only after an everyday wizard reaches the age of 20.
- It take 5 years of training for somebody predisposed to wizardhood to be able to teleport, 10 if self-taught.
- It takes 25 years of training for an everyday wizard, who is predisposed to advanced wizardhood, to become an advanced wizard (30 from non-wizard to advanced wizard). It takes 45 years if self taught (50 from non-wizard to advanced wizard).
- You can start training a 15 year old wizard (15 being the minimum age) to become an advanced wizard, and find out after 5 years they're not predisposed to advanced wizardry.
- Wizard training has no inherent material costs, but does take at least 20 hours of study/practice a week from either a wizard (to train an everyday wizard) or advanced wizard (to train another advanced wizard). It takes 40 hours study a week if self taught.
- Wizards most likely would want to be paid for training others.
- Training more than the required time has no affect, and multiple trainers only reduces the time burden on the wizards doing the training. (two wizards could train a third pre-wizard, for 10 hours a week each, but five wizards training them for 5 hours a week does not train them faster than 4 wizards at 5 hours each).
- Wizards can only train up to 5 other wizards at a time, no matter how short the training takes or how it's shared.

With the above rules, at what point (as a percentage of global population) are there enough *advanced* wizards to make official timezones necessary for governing teleportation? Is it up to the full 50% of the population I mentioned earlier in the post, or could fewer people be predisposed to wizardhood and still eventually require the establishment of timezones? Would timezones even be needed?

I'm assuming that wizards become some part of the economy either delivering people or objects vast distances almost instantly. The analogy I am thinking of, and hinted at at the start is with trains, which did eventually necessitate timezones.

(Note, although typically "[a wizard is never late, nor is he early, he arrives precisely when he means to.](https://www.quotes.net/quote/51179)", this is not the case for the wizards on this world unless they correctly understand time differences between their origin and destination.)

---

Note, this is (now) not tagged as [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) [see here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129884/discussion-about-science-based-tag-on-magic-focused-questions). Initially it was tagged this way because I would like some kind of logical/scientific reasoning as to the number provided as an answer. However the answers I've gotten have sort of ignored the stringency I associate with that tag and are better for it.

If you're struggling to get your head around how a question about wizards can be answered in a science based banner, remember Clarke's Third Law, and then re-read the question making the following substitutions: Wizard for Scientist; teleportation for FTL transportation; spell for science.

Comment: Let me know if I've missed anything important in either of the rules lists.

Comment: We can't know if you missed anything important in the list of rules you made up, because *you made them up*. TBH with all of the rules it's hard to read and make sense of the question. You might be better served if you [edit] your post to remove information that isn't necessary for people to give good answers.

Comment: I'm with sphennings on this one... you've got a lot of rules about teleportation that are only tenuously (or entirely un) related to the notion of timezones, and so you've ended up with a wall'o'text. Prune it down, it'll be easier to read and answer.

Comment: @sphennings it's possible there is a factor it looks like I assumed but didn't specify. Like if how long it takes to train a wizard turns out to be the actual limiting factor in wizard population, so they'd always be too under-populated to need timezones, then those rules are needed. I can take a guess at which rules might not be needed by the answers, but without knowing future possible answer and what assumptions they make I might struggle.

Comment: @StarfishPrime do you have any suggestions as to which rules look like they aren't needed?

Comment: If you look at any work of fiction there are uncountably many assumed but unspecified facts. **This is a feature not a bug**. If you tried to clearly specify every fact that your work of fiction relies on you'd be spending all your time telling us about your world instead of captivating an audience with a fantastic tale of teleporting wizards.

Comment: @sphennings my experience with asking a question *here*, is that it's better to be overly specific than underly so. That does obviously differ from writing a story, where the rules may end up only being revealed in time or not at all.

Comment: The answer is 42. I downvoted this question, because in my opinion, a *science-based* question should not depend on "magic handwavium" in any way. Teleportation and wizard training rules are Harry Potter subjects, not science.

Comment: @goodies the tag says "For example, we do not currently have the material science required to build a space elevator, but we can discuss the potential risks, consequences and benefits of building one based on known scientific facts." As far as I'm concerned, space elevators require "magic handwavium" because of the materials required. I don't see how the same tag can't apply in my case?

Comment: A space elevator is not a magical apparatus. It will lift people up into space mechanically, you could design it.. and calculate (scientifically assert) if your design works. It is possible to *prove*, using physics calculations, that there exist no current material strong enough to build a space elevator. However, a science based answer would e.g. provide the tensile strength required. For your question, it is impossible to devise any answer based on  scientific reasoning ! let alone calculations. Therefore it cannot be science-based.

Comment: @goodies I'm ok with you downvoting due to you not being able to answer a question using science/logic/reason, but that doesn't mean it's not possible. When I wrote the question I was looking for answers that says something like "By the mid 1800s xyz tons for goods were transported across the USA, which based on your rules would require such-and-such number of wizards. Logistically that means <scientific calculations> the coordination needed would need timezones." What tag do you think would be better than [tag:science-based] in this situation?

Comment: Instead of science-based, this question could use the "teleportation" tag. That is what your question is about. Not about science. You come up with teleportation, wizards and handwaving, you call it science-based.  But you'll only need wizards when you're *not* science-based. There is no magic in science, magic is an escape from science.

Comment: @goodie that is an excellent suggestion, but not a replacement for science based. I have made an edit based on your suggestions that might help you.

Comment: You can't call every logic reasoning "science-based" only because it involves logic. Clarke's third law sais *"Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."*. Nice observation, but it is only true, when the listener is not an engineer or a scientist being aware of the underlying working principle. When there is no underlying principle (eg: FTL travel), there is nothing *science-based* to tell about it. Clarke is an SF writer, I'm an engineer... If you would put "science fiction" as a tag, I'd take back my downvote ! (rest my case)

Comment: @goodie I still don't see the difference, but I don't think I can convince you otherwise. So what tag should I swap it for, that would exclude "magic or pseudo-science" based answers?  The only reason I put it on there is so preempt answers that purely relied on magic ("the wizards would magically know enough to not need timezones") or pseudo-science ("include an unobtanium diode to precalculate the time logistics tensor derivatives!")?

Comment: If you don't want to use SF, you could put "economy" instead ? Part of your question has to do with economic activity of these teleporters. At some point, you would indeed need fixed schedules to make that run smoothly.. I think it would be a (macro-)  economic calculation of some kind..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129884/discussion-between-pureferret-and-goodies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Railroads and Time Zones go hand-in-hand

As you identified, the closest analogy is with rail transport.

> By 1880 the nation had 17,800 freight locomotives carrying 23,600 tons of freight, and 22,200 passenger locomotives. The U.S. railroad industry was the nation's largest employer outside of the agricultural sector.

I am assuming this the numbers in use *daily*.

- [History of rail transportation in the US: Expansion and consolidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transportation_in_the_United_States#Expansion_and_consolidation_(1878%E2%80%931916))

To see how closely they are linked, see how their explosion coincided with the creation of time zones:

> On November 18, 1883, America’s railroads began using a standard time system involving four time zones, Eastern, Central, Mountain and Pacific.

- [History.com on time zones in the USA](https://www.history.com/news/when-did-the-united-states-start-using-time-zones)

> In 1860 before the transcontinentals, railroads carried less than half as much freight as inland waterways, whereas by 1890 railroads carried five times as much freight as waterways.

- [History of rail transportation in the US: Civil War and Reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transportation_in_the_United_States#Civil_War_and_Reconstruction_(1861%E2%80%931877))

So, assuming we need to be transporting "23,600 tons of freight, and 22,200 passenger" to justify the expense of creating time zones, how many Advanced wizards do we need to transport this?

#### Freight

According to [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/technology/unit-train), this freight was commonly Coal, Grain and Cement:

> By the late 20th century about 50 percent of the coal shipped in the United States was carried by these trains. Other forms of bulk cargo, such as grain and cement, were also transported in this fashion.

Coal has a density of 105.1 lb/ft³ (1,683 kg/m³), meaning this would be 449,100 cubic feet requiring 45 *thousand* advanced wizards  trips.

Barley has a density of 37.5 lb/ft³ (600 kg/m³), meaning this would be 1.2 million cubic feet requiring 120 *thousand* advanced wizard trips.

Cement has a density of 90 lb/ft³ (1450 kg/m) 525,000 cubic feet, requiring 52 *thousand* advanced wizards  trips.

No matter how you slice it, that's a lot of wizard trips. An advanced wizard works 8 hours a day, and  needs 1 minute of focus but only 5 minutes of rest meaning they can make roughly 80 trips a day.

Assuming however that they're also teaching. If 5 advanced wizards can share 5 students, and thus only need to spend 4 hours a day each training those students, that means they can only spend half their time transporting freight.

So each wizard is presumably spending 20 hours a week teaching and 20 hours teleporting (almost non-stop), they are only making 40 trips a day.

To keep things simple, you always have the same number of advanced wizards as non-advanced wizards, so on average each wizard is making ~20 trips a day (each wizard contributing 0 teleportations, and each advanced wizard contributing 40 trips).

If the average volume of freight is roughly 80 lb/ft^3 needing 59,000 wizard trips, and at 20 trips a day that's ~3,000 'average' wizards just for freight.

According to census.gov, in 1850, there were 23 million US citizens, meaning as a percentage you only need 0.013% of the population to be wizards to be able to transport enough freight to 'justify' time zones. It would be very safe to say, that you should have a fair number more wizards, because not all of them will be working in cargo transport.

#### What about Passengers?

Lets arbitrarily say, that the 22,200 passenger locomotives in 1880 could carry at most 100 passengers each, meaning we have 2,220,000 passengers. I'm going to assume only advanced wizards would be used to transport people due to the risk, and numbers able to be moved being much more than just the side-along teleportation.

If we split the 2 million passengers into 277,500 lots of 8 person chunks, and assume the similar wizarding workload of 20 hours of useful work a week, they're making 20 trips each. That results in 13,875 'average' wizards needed at a minimum (the fact they are average wizards is factored into the calculation earlier on). This means out passenger wizards are 0.06% of the population.

#### Combining Wizarding functions

That's three times as many wizards needed for passengers as for cargo, but lets round up to 20,000 average wizards total (50:50 split of advanced and non-advanced wizards), so that is 0.087% of the population. Even if we have an order of magnitude more wizards than required to 'replace' trains, we would still have <1% of the population being a wizard.

For perspective, with a 1900s population of 3,437,202 New York would have fewer than  3500 wizards from that city.

So you need no more than 1% wizards to justify having time zones, assuming they only replace railways.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see anything here that requires timezones at all.

In North America, for example, timezones were established by a consortium of railway companies because the plethora of local times made their schedules too confusing. If each town has it's own different time, then either one can cannot tell how long the journey takes, OR one cannot use the local clocks to tell when the trains arrive.

- If the train to Yuma departs at 15:10, makes 5 stops, and arrives at 19:10, is each stop listed in local time? Or Yuma time? If it's each local time, does the journey take three or four or five hours? Should I pack dinner or not? If the schedule is published in Yuma time, but my watch is on local time, then when should I be at the station?

With teleportation, there is much less information to transmit, it's not mass transportation, journey time is not a relevant factor anymore, so the same problems does not exist.

- "*Good sir, Wizard Fred will be at your house at (15:25 origin time, 15:37 destination time) to transport you to Yuma. Please be prepared, as the Wizard has many appointments today. Have your exact coinage ready as the Wizard does not make change*"

It doesn't matter what time the shipper thinks it is in their town as long as they have an ephemeris (Chapter 1: Table of time in each town), too. A moment with the ephemeris will tell them that shop-dawn is at 05:22 shop time, which is 07:34 shipper time, and they will reserve a Wizard accordingly.

As for timezones vs. using a table of times in each town, different places will use each according to culture and politics. In the real world, China and India, for example, each use a single time zone for internal political reasons (big time jump at some borders). A century later, the political reasons might have vanished, but the times remain unified due to simple social inertia. Or caste grievances and local politics might create a resurgence of local times. North America, without railways/road/aircraft, might stay with a bazillion local times -- each town jealously guarding their own from centralization. Except in Texas, of course.

Comment: Are you sure similar problems don't exist? If you say had the scenario where you send off a carrier pigeon and a token from your location and say "Please teleport a large crate of supplies here at dawn, before the shop opens" you'd need to know *when* the destination dawn is. Right?

Comment: Since I sent the pigeon, one assumes I know when my own local dawn is, or that I can consult my ephemeris (Chapter 3: Table of dawn/dusk) sitting on my shop counter. It doesn't matter what time shipper thinks it is in their town as long as they have an ephemeris (Chapter 1: Table of time in each town), too. A moment with the ephemeris will tell them that shop-dawn is at 05:22 shop time, which is 07:34 shipper time, and they will reserve a Wizard accordingly.

Comment: Don't the tables of time in each town constitute a set of timezones, albeit one for each town? It feels like it would eventually make sense to group each town by rough time difference. If that was useful, I would definitely consider it a timezone.

Comment: It's YOUR world. If that's what makes sense to you, then do that.

Comment: I'm aware I can do that, but I'm genuinely interested in what you think on the topic re: table of times in each town vs. full-blown timezones? If I didn't want to gather other views, I wouldn't have posted this question

Comment: @Pureferret thanks for the edit

Comment: I think that what @user535733 is trying to say is that they believe there is no meaningful logistical difference between a table of times for each city and 24 time zones and that choosing one or the other cannot be done by reason alone, and is therefore entirely up to the author's personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

**You can live without time zones: but your people will create them almost instantly**

Time zones have ***nothing*** to do with the mode, speed, or frequency of transportation. They have ***everything*** to do with convenience. Want to know the reasons why time zones are useful?

- Trade (you want my offices open when?)
- Diplomacy (you want the ambassador available when?)
- Hotels (you want the room available when?)

I hope I'm making my point. It's natural for people to care about what the time is right here, right now. It takes a bit 'o effort to worry about what the time is over there, even if it's right now.

So, just to say what I'm sayin' one more time. Your people will create time zones naturally because there will always be concepts of sunrise, sunset, and  "when the sun is highest in the sky" and those moments won't be true anywhere other than right here, right now.

Comment: I don't get your point. Surely if the speed of travel and communication are slow enough that there's never any need to synchronise things across great distances, formal time zones would not arise?

Comment: If communication and travel are as slow as a man on horseback, then there are no circumstances where someone would ever be worried about the time of day in a place so far from them that they would have a noticeably different time of day. So every town would just keep having their own clocks calibrated to their local noon. You could interpret that as zero time zones, or as having an extremely large amount of them (one per town).

Comment: Obviously we are dealing with a teleportation question so I think that the requirement for formal timezones has been met in this particular scenario, but you are saying that travel speed does not matter at all and I cannot believe that.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Actually, faster your mode of travel, the more critical time zones become. Get on a train, and it's possible to leave at 5pm local and arrive at 5pm destination. Teleporters mean you leave at 5pm local and arrive at 11:30am destination. Timezone syncronize "noon," not the travel. As for every clock calibrated to their local noon - that means *everyone* has their own time zone, not no one (you've got that backwards). As for the reason travel speed doesn't matter - that's literally answered by your observation of everyone setting their own clocks to noon: infinite timezones.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Unfortunately, I think you're failing to understand why time zones are useful. It isn't (and never was) to coordinate transportation. In fact, time zones become more important as the speed of transportation (or, in humanity's case, the speed of communication) approaches infinity. It matters that when you call someone, you're not calling them while they're asleep. Remember, you're calling at 10am your time zone. Without timezones, it's "10am" at their location, too ... despite it being the middle of the night.

Comment: "Actually, faster your mode of travel, the more critical time zones become." - that is exactly what I'm saying! Slow travel and communication means that you never coordinate anything over great distances, making conceiving local noon in remote places just useless trivia. The faster you can go, the greater the need to coordinate over distances great enough to make local time meaningfully different. And I agree that teleporters would need time zones for that same reason. So why do you say that travel time is irrelevant?

Comment: "that means everyone has their own time zone, not no one (you've got that backwards)." I've got nothing backwards, I literally observed that one could conceive local time for each city as an arbitrary amount of timezones. I personally think that is not a good definition of time*zone*, which should be larger than a city block (or an individual), but I pointed it out.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I think you're failing to understand why time zones are useful" I think what I'm falling to understand is your definition of time zone. When I say "formal time zone", I am referring to a great section of the planet following the exact same clock as determined by precise geographical coordinates, decided through international coordination. I don't equate time zone with "local experience of solar time" which would yield billions of time zones even in today's world.

Comment: Counter: with no time zones and everyone running on the same clock, if I say that my office opens from 0900 to 1700 everybody knows when to find me, no need to be converting times. Someone else's office might open from 1500 to 2300, giving them 2 hours to talk to me during business hours. No conversion, no discussion of "my time, your time". Discussed in the Smithsonian Mag [here](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/one-time-zone-for-the-world-127795315/)

Comment: @KeizerHarm Travel time is irrelevant because even if a person walks from the U.S. east coast to the U.S. west coast, if they don't reset their watch they'll be out of sync with local time. A time zone standardizes how everyone coordinates themselves in a fixed geographical region. Allowing people to set their own clocks would mean my neighbor's interpretation of "noon" is as valid as my own. That's chaos. Time zones allow for organization - which is why the OP can't ignore them and why they're not a function of transportation.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza That's a nice article, but the authors don't own, for example, a chain of stores across a wide geographical region. A single time zone means that business owner must print unique and individual "open/close" signs for every location rather than a single sign, economically printed, because every location opens at 8am and closes at 6pm. Neither solution (time zones or no time zones) is perfect, but it's trivial to demonstrate why time zones are useful. (\*continued\*)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza ...Imagine living in Los Angeles and listening to the news report about a murder in New York. They tell you that the murder took place at 5:45pm. You know what 5:45pm means to you and you and where you were at that moment, but you don't know what 5:45pm means in New York (unless you happen to be a student of that sort of thing). 5:45pm to you was the middle of the day. What was it in New York? Unfortunately, information like that impacts how we interpret events (a murder in broad daylight is a bigger deal than one at night). (\*continued\*)

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza ...Removing time zones from the human experience would disconnect us individually from the rest of the world with no real added benefit and make both coordination and organization of human projects outside a local scope much more complex.

Comment: What I am gathering from your comments is that your definition of time zone can be as small as a city, and is founded whenever a town builds their own clocks - arguably one is founded whenever contemplates dividing daylight in sections, making timezones as inevitable as the human experience of time. Then your answer makes sense, but my definition of timezone is a large section of the globe, demarcated by geographical coordinates, following the exact same clock which is defined with a specified offset from Greenwich. Those "formal timezones" are only necessary with coordination over distance.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Have you not taken the time to LOOK at what time zones exist? Some ARE as small as a city. Your definition of a "time zone" as large as a globe is meaningless. It's noon on one side. Midnight on the other. Not recognizing that is childish (as is, at this point, this argument).

Comment: Ok, I'm tired of your petulance and your complete refusal to even consider what other people see. If at this point you still see yourself as the all-knowing teacher and everyone in disagreement as ignorant children, then there's no point in trying to convince you otherwise.

Comment: @KeizerHarm `Ok, I'm tired of your petulance and your complete refusal to even consider what other people see.` Ditto... (You do see the irony of only believing that your ideas have been considered if they've been accepted, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Very few, if someone starts to go in for meteorology.

Let us suppose that in some regions, they do.  Wizards are endlessly teleporting in news of temperature, rainfall, and wind, and then teleporting out warnings of storms.  The thing is the location at which this data is correlated needs a framework to do it on.  If it starts to rain in Eastfield at 10:30, in Centerville at 10:30, and in Westfield at 10:30, it matters a lot if those really are the same time and the storm probably moving north or south, or if it is moving from east to west.

The telegraph made it feasible in our world.  Your wizards could make it feasible in yours.  Storm warnings could be immensely valuable but they have to be able to tell when things are happening.